# ant listMetadata not working for metadatatype report

Tags: apex, ant, migration-tool

I am trying to retrieve all the reports available in my sandbox using the below ant target and it is not returning anything.

```
  <target name="listMetadata">
    <mkdir dir="listMetadata"/>
    <sf:listMetadata MetadataType="Report" 
                     password="${sf.password}"
                     serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
                     sessionId="${sf.sessionId}"
                     username="${sf.username}"/>
  </target>
```

When I run the command `ant listMetadata` it is successfully creating the listMetadata folder and then it is doing nothing.

If I change `MetadataType` value from `Report` to some junk value, it is throwing error saying invalid metadata type.

It is driving me insane..Could somebody please help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify folder for retrieving the reports of [specific folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadataquery.htm)

```
<target name="listMetadata">
<mkdir dir="listMetadata"/>
<sf:listMetadata MetadataType="Report" folder="foldername"
                 password="${sf.password}"
                 serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
                 sessionId="${sf.sessionId}"
                 username="${sf.username}"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to list the folders?

Comment: Using sample files:
ant listMetadata -Dsf.metadataType=ReportFolder
(or DashboardFolder, EmailFolder, DocumentFolder)